# Ubuntu 16.04 Mate: Dual heads how to avoid that resolutions change?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, mate

I have a laptop connected to a TV. The two displays have different resolutions and I have different images on them. If I close the laptop lid, the resolution changes automatically on the TV! When I open the lid, the TV resolution changes again. Not back, but to an invalid resolution. I just want the TV resolution to stay as it is and the laptop display to go black when I close the lid. Is that possible? Seems most natural to me.

I have tried Power Settings, Do Nothing and Blank Screen when Lid is Closed.

Comment: FYI: Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Ubuntu-MATE for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.  https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-16-04-lts-reaches-end-of-life/19425

Comment: Yes, you are right about the support. But I still get updates. Anyway, seems 18.04 LTS has dropped 32 bits variants so I can't upgrade to that. However, your suggested command gives:

$ ubuntu-support-status 
Support status summary of 'nx-mate':

You have 67 packages (3.4%) supported until april 2021 (Community - 5y)
You have 1534 packages (77.3%) supported until april 2021 (Canonical - 5y)

You have 2 packages (0.1%) that can not/no-longer be downloaded
You have 382 packages (19.2%) that are unsupported

Comment: You are getting updates for the common base packages (ie. base system, **not** your GUI & any applications from 'universe' (which is all MATE apps)); why I suggested running `ubuntu-support-status` so you could assess for your own usage (with list options such as `--show-unsupported`).  Ubuntu-MATE provided x86/i386 in 18.04 as did most flavors.  Some flavors (Xubuntu & Lubuntu) continued into 18.10 & into 19.04 cycle too, but both are now EOL so 18.04 is the last with full x86/i386 support.   You can *release-upgrade* or install 18.04.4 flavors  (I tested many inc. MATE).

Comment: FYI:  http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/384/builds will show the daily build the 18.04.5; where you'll note x86/i386 builds are there too; so future 18.04 ISOs are still being created (ETA for 18.04.5 release is 2020-August-6)